# Sending Tweets to a Facebook Page not working

Tags: facebook, twitter, facebook-pages

Okay I've got a client's Twitter account and a Facebook page, I am a manager for the Facebook page. I have currently tried using the official Twitter Facebook app to send posts to Facebook, I was unable to get posts to send to my page but I got it to working seemlessly with my profile. I used selective tweets to post but that now isn't working anymore, it too worked with my profile too.

As that selective tweets was a recommendation from here I'm now asking for any help in resolving this. Its like my Facebook profile doesn't have authorization to post to the page, but I have full access.

I've spent too much time on this already and any help is welcome.

Comment: So, only the title explains your problem....

Comment: I'm upvoting the question because I have the same issue. An organization I work w/ used the "Selective Tweets" (https://www.facebook.com/selectivetwitter) Facebook app for their Twitter feed. This app allows you to add "#fb" to a tweet to post it to your Facebook feed. That integration has "broken". Selective Tweets works fine for individuals' Facebook feeds, but  doesn't seem to work w/ "Pages" anymore (it used to). The functionality to selectively add tweets to the Facebook feed w/ the "#fb" tag is the major the attraction of the app. I don't necessarily want every tweet going to Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

This is different, Twitter's client doesn't work for posting on Facebook!

The workflow is as follows:

1. connect your Twitter account to Facebook account
2. authorization Twitter's client to Twitter account.

Now, any time you post on Twitter, it will be synchronized on your Facebook account.